# How to connect/communicate TCP client with server on another network

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ubuntu-20.04, portforwarding

I am attempting to create a TCP client/server chat. My goal currently is to switch my client connection from using the local ip address "127.0.0.1" to being able to connect to the server that could possibly be in another computer not in the local network. Essentially if I the client was in Los Angeles, I would like to be able to communicate with the server in San Diego.

I am aware of "port forwarding" and have gone ahead and tried to configure my router. The port that the server is listening to is `8000`. The IP address I use in "LAN IP ADDRESS" is the address I obtained from going (on ubuntu) `settings->network->IPV4 address: 10.0.2.15`.

[router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5BnI.png)

Here is the code used in my `server.cpp` and `client.cpp`:

```cpp
// server.cpp
    // Attach socket to port:
    int option{1};
    if(setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &option, sizeof(option)))
    {
        logE("error in setting socket options");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // INADDR_ANY: bind socket to all local interfaces, using IPV4 family:
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if(bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)))
    {
        logE("binding socket failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

```cpp
//client.cpp
    // setup sockets method of connection:
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    /* serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); */
    /* serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("IP 1"); */
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("IP 2");

    // Connect to server:
    if(connect(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)))
    {
        logE("connection to server failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

In client.cpp "IP 1" is the IP I get when going on https://whatismyipaddress.com/, "IP 2" is the address I use that logs me into my router.

I have not been able to connect to my server using either of the two IP's, furthermore I have attempted to use different IP's in my router settings as well. Also I am aware of "static ip address" which would help the server maintain one constant IP, but I would first like to try using whatever IP address the servers machine is currently using.

Furthermore, My server.cpp is running within my Ubuntu Virtual Machine, which is hosted on Windows. Since I don't have another machine at my disposal I am testing / running this on the same VM currently for testing purposes, but once everything works I will go ahead and as a friend to test different machines.

Comment: I think you want a bridge network on your host windows OS so your Ubuntu client is on the subnet that the router manages.

Comment: @drescherjm I think that was a step in the right direction, the [link](https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/) I used helped a bit, I was able to complete 'Installing network bridge utilities in Ubuntu' and 'Creating a Network Bridge Using nm-connection-editor Tool'. Although when in the last step of going onto virtual box and pressing 'bridge adapter' under `network` I was unable to find my bridge connection name (named br0). [Reading](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=98133) mention that creating a bridge over WIFI (which is what I'm on) might not work.

Comment: A follow up question, if I where instead run my server.cpp on my host machine. Would my problem be solved? with port-forwarding on my host (windows) would my above code and information make my server work, essentially is running in my VM causing me problems.